# Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'DBSQLProvider

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

```
public abstract class ProviderBase
{
    static private ProviderBase instance = null;

    static public ProviderBase Instance
    {
          get
         {

            if (instance == null)
                instance = new DBSQLProvider();

            instance = (ProviderBase)Activator.CreateInstance(
            Type.GetType("DBSQLProvider"));

            Return instance
}
```

Comment: Remove static keyword

Comment: So? That error message is very exact, there is no question what is wrong. You "cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface DBSQLProvider". Do you have any hint that you should be able to? Is the error message wrong?

Comment: @nvoigt I guess static methods and classes cannot be instantiated what do u recon?

Comment: @apomene My guess is as good as yours as we both don't know what the "class" in question looks like or even if it is a class at all.

Comment: I found the solution, I commented out the line 'instance = new DBSQLProvider();
' thank you